# Get transaction id after instant paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I am new with paypal and trying to make payment with paypal. I found code to show Buy button on my website and it successfully redirects me to paypal. After successful payment i want to store user trasnaction id into my database. But in response i am not getting transaction id.

Here is my code:

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business_email@gmail.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Job Post">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25">
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url('account/paypal_cancel');?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url('account/paypal_return');?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url('account/paypal_return');?>">
                <input type="image" class="hidden" name="submit" name="paypal_submit" id="paypal_submit"
                src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
                alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
            </form>
```

After successful payment, response i am getting:

```
                        Array
                    (
                        [mc_gross] => 25.00
                        [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
                        [address_status] => confirmed
                        [payer_id] => K7MH34Q4ZNN12
                        [tax] => 0.00
                        [address_street] => 1 Main St
                        [payment_date] => 23:25:32 Aug 03, 2016 PDT
                        [payment_status] => Completed
                        [charset] => windows-1252
                        [address_zip] => 95131
                        [first_name] => Payer First name
                        [mc_fee] => 1.28
                        [address_country_code] => US
                        [address_name] => Name
                        [notify_version] => 3.8
                        [custom] => 
                        [payer_status] => verified
                        [business] => business_email@gmail.com
                        [address_country] => United States
                        [address_city] => San Jose
                        [quantity] => 1
                        [payer_email] => payer_email@gmail.com
                        [verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Apes4ffYPHmXs3U0H9m6oiBFZWDe
                        [txn_id] => 4HH86447NJ982154T
                        [payment_type] => instant
                        [last_name] => Last Name
                        [address_state] => CA
                        [receiver_email] => business_email@gmail.com
                        [payment_fee] => 1.28
                        [receiver_id] => C4VX55Z5QJG87
                        [txn_type] => web_accept
                        [item_name] => Job Post
                        [mc_currency] => USD
                        [item_number] => 1
                        [residence_country] => US
                        [test_ipn] => 1
                        [handling_amount] => 0.00
                        [transaction_subject] => 
                        [payment_gross] => 25.00
                        [shipping] => 0.00
                        [auth] => A5eWy6N2pRotb5qNnmxnnEWAabmNZfgr0pGGMFWYVoXqrcmQpINk7nAB0fNCv0m66XgcwMbCVIWqtW0q7yldjHg
                    )
```

I want the transaction id, but there is not transaction id in response.

Can anyone assist me that how can i get transaction id using paypal response.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `[txn_id] => 4HH86447NJ982154T`

Comment: but this id is not matching the actual transaction id. I checked by login to paypal account but transaction id is different.

Comment: Can i get paypal transaction id from txn_id?

Comment: The buyer and seller may get different IDs, so make sure you're comparing the correct ones.  If this is from IPN data, for example, that would be from the seller account, so make sure you're not comparing that against the buyer transaction ID.